# How to display differents file (mp3, jpeg) from a folder

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();

include('config/connexionDB.php');
include('functions/search_user.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit;
}

// On récupère les informations de l'utilisateur connecté
$req = $DB->query("SELECT * 
    FROM posts
    ORDER BY id ");

$req = $req->fetchAll();

?>`
<?php
    foreach($req as $r){  

        $info = new SplFileInfo($r['fileNameNew']);

        $extaudio = array('.mp3', '.flac');

        $extimage = array('.png', '.jpg');

        if($info = $extaudio){
        ?>
             <div class="card" style="width: 45rem;">
                 <div class="card-body" align="center">
                     <h6 align="left"><?= $r['author'] ?></h6>
                     <?php echo"<audio src='uploads/".$r['fileNameNew']."' controls>;"; ?>
                     <h3><?= $r['content'] ?></h5>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Like</a>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</a>
                 </div>
             </div><br>
        <?php
        }elseif($info = $extimage){
        ?>
             <div class="card" style="width: 45rem;">
                 <div class="card-body" align="center">
                     <h6 align="left"><?= $r['author'] ?></h6>
                     <h3><?= $r['content'] ?></h5>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Like</a>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</a>
                     <?php echo "<img src='uploads/".$r['fileNameNew']."'>"; ?>
                 </div>
             </div><br>
         <?php
         }
    }
?>`
```

Comment: Is there a question? Describe your input, expected output, actual output, any error messages, and any relevent log entries

Comment: I have no error message but my files (mp3, jpg) do not want to display. Can you help me? It's a system of post.

Comment: There's nothing in your error_log? warnings/notices, etc ?

Comment: `$info = $extimage` is wrong. Use `==` for a comparison. Both in the if and the elseif

Comment: A single `=` assigns a value

Comment: Plus, info is an object, it will never equal an array

Comment: I have a warning "The HTTP "Content-Type" "image / jpeg" is not supported. The loading of the media resource http://127.0.0.1/sharing/uploads/5bcc788c89d649.02013790.jpg failed."

Comment: what line causes that?

Comment: Thank you but when I put the == I get no result in the display

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: With the == I have no warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.

`$info = $extimage` is wrong. Use `==` for a comparison. Both in the if and the elseif.

`if($info == $extaudio){`

A single equals assigns a value, ie. `$age = 40` sets the age to 40, `$age == 40` returns `true` or `false` if $age does equal 40 or not.

Secondly, `$info = new SplFileInfo($r['fileNameNew']);`. `$info` is an object, so comparing them directly will always retirn false.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

Instead, get the file extension and check if it is in your array.

http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php

```
if(in_array($info->getExtension(), $extaudio)){
```

Hope this helps! Good luck

Comment: did it work? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it does not work...Thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: what happens now? Try removing the dots from your arrays, getExtension doesn't return the dot

Comment: It works, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you mark this answer please?

Comment: How? I am new on Stack :)

Comment: just tick the check to the left of my question! :-D

Comment: It's done, thanks you

Comment: Thanks a lot, and good luck with all your development!